# Android: Unable to upgrade sqlite database from SD Card

Tags: android, sqlite

I have my SQlite table on SD card for my app. Now, I have to upgrade my database. But, after onUpgrade, onCreate of SQLiteOpenHelper never gets called.

Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + "/"
        + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/MyApp.sqlite";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.e(TAG, "DB onCreate");
    // String CREATE_SCHEMA =
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Master ("
            + "  ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,"
            + "  UserName varchar(50) NOT NULL ,"
            + "  DriverID int NOT NULL ,"
            + "  DriverName varchar(100) NULL ,"
            + "  MobilePrint int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,"
            + "  LastSyncUTC text NULL ,"
            + "  SchemaVersion TEXT NOT NULL ,"
            + "  PasswordHash TEXT NULL ," + "  SyncMinutes int NOT NULL ,"
            + "  LatestAppVersion TEXT NOT NULL" + ");");

    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO: handle updates when they are necessary
    Log.e(TAG, "DB onUpgrade");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "Master");
}
```

I am not getting why, it is not upgrading to new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onUpgrade, you have to do all the work of recreating the database. onCreate() isn't called after onUpgrade.